# PowerShell logon script as admin

Tags: powershell, active-directory, gpo

I have a PowerShell script that I need to run at user logon.
The script uses the AD module to see if a users is part of a group and get other info, plus also I get local variables like:

```
$env:DOMAINNAME
$env:USERNAME
$env:APPDATA
$env:TEMP
```

And is why I need it to run at logon but I think is a permission issue.

Any idea how could I do this? I tried adding the script under *User Configuration → Policies → Windows Settings → Scripts → Logon*, and it did not work, also tried under *Computer Configuration*.

Added `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` as parameter and still nothing.

I also tried to add is as a scheduled task and run it as other user but still no luck.

Comment: Why would you need to run a startup script as a different user?

Comment: To run it as an account with higher permissions.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well run that as the system account.

Comment: I just tried running it with the NT AUTHORITY\System account and the script at the end is supposed to generate a file and i does generates the file but is empty, it can be cause it might not have access to import the AD module.   but none of the machine will have access to it now that i think of. Any other idea?

Comment: Why wouldn't it have access to the AD module?  That depends on the RSAT feature being enabled.  And I'm assuming it's a domain-joined machine with view rights to AD?

Comment: What do you need to do in the script? I generally recommend Group Policy preferences with item-level targeting.

Comment: It is a domain environment and i opened powershell with the domain user account i am using for testing and i tried to import-module AD. i got: Import-Module : The specified module 'activedirectory' was not loaded because no valid     module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ import-module <<<<  activedirectory
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (activedirectory:String) [Import-    Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand .

Comment: @Bill_Stewart the scripts builds the user signature and set it as default on outlook. i get the $env:username to then make a search in AD for the user information, loads an html template and replaces the information to save the builded signature on $env:appdata and other things like copy the signature to a shared folder that other scripts laters set it on Office365

Comment: If you want to use the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module on a client computer you must download and install the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) first, before you can enable the module under *Programs and Features*. On server systems the RSAT are already present, but you still need to enable the module in the Server Manager (via *Add Roles and Features*).

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? if not this will mean i will have to download it, install it and enable it on every user machine which  would be 450+ which is not in consideration for this.

Comment: You can access AD using only .NET classes, but the code must be redesigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you shared your code in one of the other comments, I can make some assumptions about what you're trying to achieve and help with that. So let's break it down.

## ActiveDirectory Module

The first thing we need to do is remove the dependency on the ActiveDirectory module. As explained by some of the comments here, the ActiveDirectory module is a built-in component of the RSAT suite. When this script is running on your client computers, this won't be available and we don't want to make it available as it creates a large dependency overhead and exposes admin utilities to your users.

The cmdlets you're using are simply `Get-ADUser`, `Get-ADGroup` and `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`. These are search cmdlets using the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP), and so we can replace them with our own search functions using .NET classes.

#### Get-ADUser

We can replace the `Get-ADUser` search cmdlet with our own function defined at runtime like so:

```
function Get-ADUser 
{
    Param ( [string]$Identity = $null )
    IF ($Identity)
    {

        $UserSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $UserSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$("DC=$(($ENV:USERDNSDOMAIN).Replace(".",",DC="))")"
        $UserSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(SAMAccountName=$Identity))"
    
        $UserSearcher.FindAll() | foreach {New-Object PSObject -Property:$_.Properties}
    }
}
```

#### Get-ADGroup

We also need to replace the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet so that we can grab the AD Groups you've specified in your `$OfficeLocations` list.

```
function Get-ADGroup 
{
    Param ( [string]$Identity = $null )
    IF ($Identity)
    {

        $GroupSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $GroupSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$("DC=$(($ENV:USERDNSDOMAIN).Replace(".",",DC="))")"
        $GroupSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(SAMAccountName=$Identity))"
               
        $GroupSearcher.FindAll() | foreach {New-Object PSObject -Property:$_.Properties}
    }
}
```

#### Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

This cmdlet doesn't need to be replaced - not because it will work on it's own, but instead because you don't require it to achieve your desired end result. You have used it to retrieve group memberships from an AD User, however the AD User has a list of their memberships attached to their AD User object. So in essence, we can get a list of an AD User's memberships directly from the AD User object, and we will do that like this:

```
$userObject = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:USERNAME
$objGroup = $userObject.memberOf
```

What you will notice at this point is that the result set is not the group names, but their distinguished names. This is also just a string array of those distinguished names, and you will have to make some modifications to the rest of your code's comparison operators that filters this list of groups.

## Deploying your code

The second thing we need to look at is how you're deploying this code. There are numerous ways that you can achieve this, but let's assume that you're able to get the script deployed to the end user and assume that it runs.

#### Context

The method you use to deploy this code needs to align with the code itself. If your script makes assumptions about the context it's running in (such as using `$env:USERNAME` to gather the user's SAMAccountName for AD), then you need to ensure that the deployment method makes this assumption as well. The script as it is right now is making that assumption - the assumption that it's the user's own context running this code.

To support this assumption, we need to make sure that the deployment method is going to run the script *as the user*.

#### Dependencies

Now we know that the code is running as the user in their own context on the user's machine, and we know that the code accesses external resources such as Active Directory, we need to make sure that the user has the rights to these dependencies the code has, to ensure that the code will work.

Make sure you go through your code and list out all the tasks that the code performs. By that, I mean note that the code will *read* the user's own AD object, and it will *read* a network location to access signature files, and it will *read* & *write* to the user's own registry, as well as *write* to the user's appdata path.

## In Conclusion

With those dependencies verified, and with the deployment method lining up with the code, you should have yourself a working product. Your code suggests there is a lot you have to learn about Powershell but if you keep at it and hone your understanding of fundamentals, you'll be ok. Keep learning, keep breaking stuff, and always remember to have fun along the way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and the help on this issue! This is something i will start to look into right now but with this i can see a light. 
As you notice on my script i dont have much experience with powershell as i recently started learning and this is the biggest project ive got into so fa. I have no experience calling the .NET classes but this definitely gives me an idea to where to go from here to complete the script. I will work on this and post the outcomes for you all who helped me to know. Thank you!